# LibreOffice Calc stop slow search

Tags: performance, search, libreoffice

I have attempted a text search on a large (500 000 row) spreadsheet that has crippled LibreOffice for the last 20 minutes. How can I stop it?

It has interrupted *all* open documents, not just the one doing the search.